# jQuery: calculate the height of multiple elements and apply them to the top-margin of each parent

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to calculate the height of a `div` containing text, and to add that value to the top-margin of its parent. These blocks of text are intended as captions for images, so their height will vary one from the other. I have it currently so that jQuery calculates the height of the first instance of this in the HTML, and applies this to the margin of that *and all following parents* of the given class. As a result, only the first caption drops down the correct amount, the others just drop down the amount required of the first instance.

I need jQuery to calculate things individually for each instance. I had wondered whether it involved `.each` in some way, but I'm not sure. What do I have to do?

Here is an example of how it is currently: http://www.robbiedawson.com/text/article1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 var elements = $(".imagecaption")
 var topMargin = $(elements).outerHeight();

 if (innerWidth > 980) {

     $(".imagewrap").hover(function() {
         $(this).css("margin-top", topMargin);

     }, function() {
         $(this).css("margin-top", 7);
     }
   )
 };
});
</script>
```

Here's the html:

```
<div class="imagewrap"> 
    <img class="image" src="" style="">
    <div class="imagecaption">The caption goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of effort for such a funky effect, honestly. Why not just slide the caption down?

Comment: Slide the caption down over the image? Yes, that would be more sensible. I'm just learning about what's possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the height from child when the hover event fires.

```
 $(".imagewrap").hover(function() {
     var topMargin = $(this).children(".imagecaption").outerHeight();
     $(this).css("margin-top", topMargin);

 }, function() {
     $(this).css("margin-top", 7);
 }
```

Comment: Brilliant. It works, of course. This is going to help me a lot. Thanks.